# How do I sound-proof a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, sound-proofing

I think most people would agree that sound proofing a bathroom is a swell idea. Since bathrooms are special rooms (high humidity), what are some tips and techniques you can use to sound proof one without running into water/mold problems down the line?

I am asking in the context of a bathroom in the process of being remodeled. This allows major "design" changes but probably not significant structural changes.

Comment: This a new bathroom, or are you trying to do this to an existing one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a second layer of drywall with [Green Glue](http://www.greengluecompany.com/) for sound isolation; not shilling, just heard very good things about it and plan to use it to soundproof a den.

Comment: When doing two layers of drywall for soundproofing, you want to make sure the seams are offset. If one sheet makes it floor to ceiling, do both vertical but start one layer with a half sheet. Otherwise, hang one layer vertical and other horizontal.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLjhrXFo0Kw

Answer (score 5):

I would use a sound proofing insulation in the walls, then instead of using normal drywall, use a moisture resistant or mold resistant type.  Thicker drywall will also help with sound deadening.

At last resort, put in a super loud ceiling fan that turns on with the light, that way even if it'll cover up the sound of you peeing. :)

Comment: Speaking of pee sounds, maybe you could sound proof the toilet itself!

Comment: It might not be the sound of the peeing, but the sound of the flush, if he's got one of those pressure-assist low-flow toilets.  I nearly had a heart attack the first time I encountered one in a hotel bathroom.  (I've heard they've gotten better, but are still noisy)